# Unable to shift the table view cell when it is swiped to delete

Tags: ios

I have a table view with all required datasource and delegate methods.

On running when i swipe the cell,the delete button appears but APPEARS OVER THE cell contents.
The cell doesn't shift.

I expected the functionality to move the cells is present in the following code,but it doesn't

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {

        [[NoteManager sharedManager] removeNoteAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this simple issue 
A quick help is appriciated..

Answer (score 0):

When you add subviews to the cell, make sure you add them to the cell's `contentView`, not the cell.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:someSubview];
```

The frame of the `contentView` will be adjusted as needed for various cell decorations including the Delete button.